# Angular 6 define JSON format of Date

Tags: json, angular

I want to make a POST request to an API. The API expects a date in the following format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.
I have a request object with an attribute of Type `Date`.

When I make the POST request via

```
this.http.post<ResponseObject>(url, objectWithDateAttribute, headers);
```

My API throws an error because the JSON format of the attribute of type date doesn't match.

How can I change the JSON format of the Date attribute when I make the POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API requires an ISO String you can obtain by calling `toISOString()` [method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp) on your date object.

Answer (score 0):

Your format is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS.
let dateAttrib = new Date().toISOString().split('T').join(' ');

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using angular [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe). You can convert the date object `objectWithDateAttribute` by looking at this sample example. Note the `providers` array and it should also be injected inside the `constructor`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers : [DatePipe]
})
export class AppComponent  {

 someDate = new Date();
  constructor(private dp : DatePipe) {
     console.log(this.dp.transform(this.someDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'))
  }
}
```

Comment: `objectWithDateAttribute ` has multiple attributes. Only one of them is of type Date. Can I achieve with that pipe that every time `objectWithDateAttribute ` is converted into JSON the specific date attribute has this format?

Comment: You should do formatting before building the request data. Probably inside that the `setter` method of that property.